# The intuitive interpretation of $v\cdot v^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

### General Question:

We know for a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v^T\cdot v=\|v\|_2^2$, which could be interpreted as the square of the length of this vector. However, what is an intuitive interpretation, if any, of $v\cdot v^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

### Specific Background:

> The background is related to graph theory; it would be great if you have already had some knowledge on this since the following parts contain many basic concepts of graph theory. If you are not interested, you could just focus on the general question and ignore the following part. :)

This question is inspired by the *Laplacian matrix* $L$ of an *undirected graph* $G$. That is, 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
L=D\cdot D^T
\end{equation} 
where $D$ is the *incidence matrix* of $G$. In addition, the Laplacian matrix can be computed in another way, i.e., 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
L=\Delta-A
\end{equation}
 where $\Delta$ is the *degree matrix* and $A$ is the *adjacency matrix* of $G$ respectively. The interesting thing here is the Laplacian matrix $L$, incidence matrix $D$, degree matrix $\Delta$ and adjacency matrix $A$ have their intuitive interpretations related to the topology of the graph $G$. It is easy to understand what $L$ is by the formula (2) but I just could not understand (1) in an intuitive way related to the structure of $G$, and how (1) and (2) is equivalent? I  think my specific questions in this graph-theory background could be generalized to the general question in the field of Linear Algebra since $D$ could be decomposed into several column vectors, e.g. $D=[d_1 \ d_2 \ d_3]$, so 
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
L=D\cdot D^T= \begin{bmatrix} d_1 & d_2 & d_3 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} d_1^T \\ d_2^T \\ d_3^T \end{bmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^{3} d_i\cdot d_i^T
\end{equation}
But I am not sure if this decomposition helps me understand this specific background better or not (we could decompose $D$ into several row vectors as well).

### Note:

I am not sure whether my generalization from the specific background to the general question is a good way for me to understand graph theory or not. But any help would be appreciated be it related to graph-theory background or related to merely linear algebra or related to other fields such as physics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its the value of a bilinear map into the set of real matrices.

So, a linear map $$\psi : \mathbb{R}^n \otimes \mathbb{R}^n \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$$

where in general for elementary tensors $x \otimes y$, we have $\psi(x \otimes y) = xy^T$

Also, its somewhat easy to see that this is an isomorphism. So, you can think of $vv^T$ as $v \otimes v$

Comment: Tensor product seems more complicated...